# wx - wxWebView dont navigate to other pages

Tags: wxwidgets

I using wxWebView to print html file. I want open link in default browser. I can do this, but i cant stop navigation and my page in wxWebView changed. How can i stop this? I try this

```
void navigatingEvent(wxWebViewEvent &e)
{
    htmlView->Stop();
    wxLaunchDefaultBrowser(e.GetURL());
}
```

but this don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to veto the event by calling `e.Veto()` to prevent the default processing from happening.